# How to make method inside method and catch the name of function above method in java which make the

Tags: java, function, for-loop, methods, logic

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class allPurpose {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        theMain();

    }

    public static void theMain() {

        System.out.println("Welcome to All purpose java Programme \n Please select from the following:");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("========MENU=========");
        System.out.println("1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Subtraction");
        System.out.println("3. Multiplication");
        System.out.println("4. Division");
        System.out.println("5. Table");
        System.out.println("6. Square and Cube");
        System.out.println("7. Exit");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        switch (n) {

            case 1:
                addition();
                break;
            case 2:
                subtraction();
                break;
            case 3:
                multiplication();
                break;
            case 4:
                division();
                break;
            case 5:
                table();
                break;
            case 6:
                squareAndCube();
                break;
            case 7:
                exit();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;
        }


    }

    public static void addition() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nSelected Addition\n");
        System.out.print("Enter one Number \t");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter another Number\t");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = (a + b);
        System.out.println("\n \t Addition: " + c);
        System.out.println("\n!continue");
        System.out.println("1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.print("Select one option \t");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                addition();
                break;
            case 2:
                theMain();
                break;
            case 3:
                exit();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;

        }


    }

    public static void subtraction() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nSelected Subtraction\n");
        System.out.print("Enter one Number \t");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter another Number\t");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = (a - b);
        System.out.println("\n \t Subtraction: " + c);
        System.out.println("\n!continue");
        System.out.println("1. Subtraction");
        System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.print("Select one option \t");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                subtraction();
                break;
            case 2:
                theMain();
                break;
            case 3:
                exit();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;

        }


    }

    public static void multiplication() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nSelected Multiplication\n");
        System.out.print("Enter one Number \t");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter another Number\t");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = (a * b);
        System.out.println("\n \t Multiplication: " + c);
        System.out.println("\n!continue");
        System.out.println("1. Multiplication");
        System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.print("Select one option \t");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                multiplication();
                break;
            case 2:
                theMain();
                break;
            case 3:
                exit();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;

        }
    }
    public static void division() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nSelected Division\n");
        System.out.print("Enter one Number \t");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter another Number\t");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = (a / b);
        System.out.println("\n \t Division: " + c);
        System.out.println("\n!continue");
        System.out.println("1. Division");
        System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.print("Select one option \t");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                division();
                break;
            case 2:
                theMain();
                break;
            case 3:
                exit();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;

        }
    }
    public static void table() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nSelected Table\n");
        System.out.print("Enter Number to get Table of it  \t");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++){
            int b = a*i;
            System.out.println(a + " * " + (i) + " = " +b);

        }
        System.out.println("\n!continue");
        System.out.println("1. Table");
        System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.print("Select one option \t");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
               table();
                break;
            case 2:
                theMain();
                break;
            case 3:
                exit();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;

        }

    }
    public static void squareAndCube() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter one number to check its Square and Cube \t ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int s = (a * a);
        int c = (a * a * a);
        System.out.println("\t Square: " + s + "\n \tCube: " + c);

        System.out.println("\n!continue");
        System.out.println("1. Square and Cube");
        System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.print("Select one option \t");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                squareAndCube();
                break;
            case 2:
                theMain();
                break;
            case 3:
                exit();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;

        }
    }

    public static void exit() {
        System.out.println("\n \tThank you have a nice day ahead! :)");
    }
    }
```

I am making calculator in java with many features
We can see that I have added following code on every method

```
    System.out.println("\n!continue");
    System.out.println("1. Addition");
    System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
    System.out.println("3. Exit");
    System.out.print("Select one option \t");

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            addition();
            break;
        case 2:
            theMain();
            break;
        case 3:
            exit();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            break;

}
```

just the difference is second line of every method is different, in above example code its

```
System.out.println("1. Addition");
```

in above example its addition according to the method name (in Addition method it used so )
in subtraction method it is subtraction 
and so on 

**so can we make one method to keep all of the above code and in that code also we do something which auto catch second line according to method in which we are using 
like in division second line of  it will System.out.println("1. Division"); which  auto catch according to the method**

Comment: If you're asking what I think, then no there's no way to do this automatically.  Everything is basically a variation on what you have, which is just to call the right routine in a `switch` statement.  Other possibilities include using a `Map` or reflection.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `System.out.println` is not the only place where your methods differ, but also (more important) in `case 1` of `switch` construct where each method recursively calls itself. Second, there is a problem with your design, whose solution will also solve the original problem. Notice that from each method you are calling another method, even in the case when user requested going back to Main Menu. Stack gets larger and larger! So let's first rewrite `theMain` method:

```
public static void theMain() {

    System.out.println("Welcome to All purpose java Programme \n Please select from the following:");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    while (n != 7) {
        System.out.println("========MENU=========");
        System.out.println("1. Addition");
        System.out.println("2. Subtraction");
        System.out.println("3. Multiplication");
        System.out.println("4. Division");
        System.out.println("5. Table");
        System.out.println("6. Square and Cube");
        System.out.println("7. Exit");

        n = sc.nextInt();
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
               addition();
               break;
            case 2:
               subtraction();
               break;
            case 3:
                multiplication();
                break;
            case 4:
                division();
                break;
            case 5:
                table();
                break;
            case 6:
                squareAndCube();
                break;
            case 7:
                exit();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are in the loop which breaks in case that user wants to leave the program.

Now let's rewrite one of methods:

```
public static void addition() {
    while (true) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nSelected Addition\n");
        System.out.print("Enter one Number \t");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter another Number\t");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = (a + b);        
        System.out.println("\n \t Addition: " + c);
        if (!proceed("Addition"))
            break;
    }
}
```

And finally, code of `proceed` method:

```
public static bool proceed(String method) {
    System.out.println("\n!continue");
    System.out.println("1. " + method);
    System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
    System.out.print("Select one option \t");

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            return true;
        case 2:
             return false;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            break;
    }
}
```

Notice that `exit` is now only possible from Main Menu.

Answer to your question - method name can be retrieved through reflection, but I believe that is an overkill for this simple program.

Comment: you  have really used your time to answer but i am new in the JAVA not much understood i think your answer will solve the question i will try on my program

Comment: @RishitShah No problem, let me know if anything needs to be explained in more detail.

Comment: is it possible you send me java file of it tried but didnt understand

Comment: @RishitShah Which part you didn't understand? I just added `while` loop in `theMain` method and in `addition` method (as an example how should be done in other methods). Common code is now separated in `proceed` method. Code is almost the same as yours, just better organized and without duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using reflection if you add a simple interface:

```
public class allPurpose {
    //All current methods here
    interface Action{
        void doOption();
    }
}
```

Then, just index into the array of your methods.

In `theMain()` you can do:

```
public static void theMain() {
    //Other code here

    //instead of switch statement do:
    Action[] initialOptions = new Action[] {
        new Action() { public void doOption() { addition(); } },
        new Action() { public void doOption() { subtraction(); } },
        new Action() { public void doOption() { multiplication(); } },
        new Action() { public void doOption() { division(); } },
        new Action() { public void doOption() { table(); } },
        new Action() { public void doOption() { squareAndCube(); } },
        new Action() { public void doOption() { exit(); } },
    };

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    if(n < 1 || > 7)
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    else
        actions[n-1].doOption();
}
```

Use a helper method in the other methods, where repeat is the current method:

```
public static void continueOptions(int i, Action repeat){
    Action[] options = new Action[] {
        repeat,
        new Action() { public void doOption() { theMain(); } },
        new Action() { public void doOption() { exit(); } },
    };
    if(i < 1 || > 3)
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    else
        options[i-1].doOption();
}
```

After this, for example `addition` would look like:

```
public static void addition() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nSelected Addition\n");
    System.out.print("Enter one Number \t");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter another Number\t");
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    int c = (a + b);
    System.out.println("\n \t Addition: " + c);
    System.out.println("\n!continue");
    System.out.println("1. Addition");
    System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
    System.out.println("3. Exit");
    System.out.print("Select one option \t");

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    continueOptions(int i, new Action() { public void doOption() { addition(); } });

}
```

Comment: you  have really used your time to answer but i am new in the JAVA not much understood i think your answer will solve the question i will try on my program

Answer (score 1):

Consider using interfaces to make more generic methods; for example, addition/subtraction/multiplication and division can be modeled as one method as follows:

```
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    switch (n) {

    case 1:
        doCalculator("Addition", (a,b) -> a+b);
        break;
    case 2:
        doCalculator("Subtraction", (a,b) -> a-b);
        break;
    case 3:
        doCalculator("Multiplication", (a,b) -> a*b);
        break;
    case 4:
        doCalculator("Division", (a,b) -> a/b);
        break;
```

The generic calculator which takes two inputs, and outputs one value:

```
    public static void doCalculator(String title, Calculator calc) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nSelected "+title+"\n");
    System.out.print("Enter one Number \t");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter another Number\t");
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    int c = calc.calculate(a, b);
    System.out.println("\n \t "+title+": " + c);
    System.out.println("\n!continue");
    System.out.println("1. "+title);
    System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
    System.out.println("3. Exit");
    System.out.print("Select one option \t");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    switch (n) {
    case 1:
        doCalculator(title, calc);
        break;
    case 2:
        theMain();
        break;
    case 3:
        exit();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        break;

    }
    sc.close();
}
```

The key is to use an interface which models the calculation:

```
interface Calculator {
    int calculate(int a, int b);
}
```

You can create other interfaces which closely model other types of calculations to expand the flexibility of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to a method and use switch case inside that method :

```
public static void callthismethod(int number){

    System.out.println("\n!continue");

    switch (number) {
        case 1 : System.out.println("1. Addition");break;
        case 2 : System.out.println("1. Subtraction");break;
        case 3 : System.out.println("1. Multiplication");break;
        ..............
        ..............
        ..............
    }

    System.out.println("2. Main Menu");
    System.out.println("3. Exit");
    System.out.print("Select one option \t");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            if(number == 1){
                addition();
            }
            else if(number == 2){
                subtraction();
            }
            else if(number == 3){
                multiplication();
            }
            ...........
            ...........
            ...........
            break;
        case 2:
            theMain();
            break;
        case 3:
            exit();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: do you think it will work reason behind, how to distinguish

Comment: @RishitShah, you need to pass specific value as a parameter when calling the method

Comment: you might be right but i didnt understand one thing if some one want to go to main menu what they have to enter

Comment: @RishitShah, you need to enter 2 when you enter the method, maybe this is not the exact thing you want, but you can make use of this method as a helper method

Comment: if he enter 2 ,how computer will realize that this is 2 of switch case or of if-else